# Splunk query for showing day wise percentage

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard, splunk-calculation

Ask: Generate a graph which should show day wise percentage of API success/Availability data in a Splunk dashboard.

Data(search based on specific string) is based on the total number of Success calls on API Named as 'ABC' and Total number of failure calls on API Named as 'ABC' for given period.

Appreciate any pointers for generating the Splunk query for displaying success percentage in day wise graph.

Query tried :

```
index=app_index "ABC Api call success"  
| stats count(unique_success_string) as sucessCall
| appendcols [search index=app_index "ABC Failure call" | stats(unique_failure_string) as fialuresCall] 
| eval percentage = (sucessCall/fialuresCall)*100 
| fields _time percentage
```

Comment: How does that query not meet expectations?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your time period will be longer than a day?

Comment: @RichG example: if i select for last 3 days , graph not displaying percentage of success calls /day ? i m looking for that

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, time period can be day / for longer period - graph should show day wise success percentage data

Answer (score 1):

To get per-day statistics, the results need to broken up by day.  Use the `bin` or `timechart` command for that.  Also, the `appendcols` command is unnecessary as the `stats` and `timechart` commands can calculate two numbers at the same time.

```
index=app_index ("ABC Api call success" OR "ABC Failure call")
| bin span=1d _time
| stats sum(eval(match(_raw,unique_success_string))) as sucessCall,
        sum(eval(match(_raw,unique_failure_string))) as fialuresCall by _time
| eval percentage = (sucessCall/fialuresCall)*100 
| fields _time percentage
```